# install failed[118, -12], reason: Check certificate error : :Invalid signature. Signed with wrong key, changed signature file or changed package file

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

While I am going to run my tizen tv application with Tizen studio(version 4.6) and facing this error on the console

```
install failed[118, -12], reason: Check certificate error : :Invalid signature. Signed with wrong key, changed signature file or changed package file.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://forum.developer.samsung.com/t/smart-tv-certificaate-issue/22914 It seems the root CA has just expired two days ago. Creating a new distributor certificate or temporarily changing the device's time setting may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to create a certificate for the error shown in the console. I'm attaching a link to help you create certificates regarding the Tizen Studio TV App, which helped me to resolve the issue.

https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/getting-started/setting-up-sdk/creating-certificates.html

Answer (score 0):

I created Tizen certificate is for the emulator. The Samsung profile certificate is for an actual TV, (wish they would just say that). Make sure you do partner cert cuz that's all that works. It worked once in emulator, I was happy. But then it stopped running the emulator and **I got your same error**. I tried restarting my local server, restarting vscode, didn't work. Then for some reason, **opening the certificate manager window** made it run successfully? I didn't change anything. Not sure if this could help you.

It is wild how picky it is about certificates though.